# Is there any way to organize my DF in the format i need using python or R?

Tags: r

I'm struggling to find a way to organize my data frame in the format I need.
The database I'm working with provide me a data frame as it shows in the image:

[Unorganized data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGMCd.png)

the thing is there's some date on the column ID and in the NF column there's characters.
I'm trying a way to organize the dataframe as it follows:
[Organized Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpLUz.png)

Where the column ID have only the ID's and in the NF column I have the ID's related to the respective NF.

I was thinking in a way to extract the ID's between the date format who are in the column and complete the NF column with the NF in the column who are in the same row of the date.

I'm currently doing it manually in spreadsheets but if it increase too much will be impossible and my coding skills are bellow the challenge at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

The `mutate` makes anything in the `nf` column NA unless it starts with 3 digits and a hyphen. You could adjust that [regex](https://regexr.com) pattern if needed for your larger dataset. `fill` then copies down the `nf` values you want. And the `filter` removes the rows containing dates.

(You could use `%>%` instead of `|>` if not on a recent version of R.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~nf,
  "27/07/2021", "001-00011598",
  "5683", "BASE P/ NOTEBOOK NBC-50BK C3TECH",
  "10180", "SUPORTE MONITOR 17 A 32 T1224N ELG",
  "10208", "SUPORTE F160N DUPLO P/ MONITOR 17 A 27 ELG",
  "12551", "MINI ADAPTADOR XC-BTT-04 XCELL",
  "13121", "GABINETE PINK TGC-PO3P T-DAGGER",
  "13306", "CASE HD + SSD CGHD-G34 EXBOM",
  "27/07/2021", "001-00011599",
  "12551", "MINI ADAPTADOR XC-BTT-04 XCELL",
  "12674", "SUPORTE FIXO GENIUS ELG",
  "13306", "CASE HD + SSD CGHD-G34 EXBOM"
)

df2 <- df |> 
  mutate(nf = if_else(!str_starts(nf, "\\d{3}-"), NA_character_, nf)) |> 
  fill(nf) |> 
  filter(!str_detect(id, "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"))

df2

#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>   id    nf          
#>   <chr> <chr>       
#> 1 5683  001-00011598
#> 2 10180 001-00011598
#> 3 10208 001-00011598
#> 4 12551 001-00011598
#> 5 13121 001-00011598
#> 6 13306 001-00011598
#> 7 12551 001-00011599
#> 8 12674 001-00011599
#> 9 13306 001-00011599
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It worked pretty well, thank you soo much, I didn't knew the !str_starts so I was trying something much more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

1. Within an `ifelse` statement identify the pattern xxx-xxxxxxx all numbers.
2. `fill` the `NA` down with the identified pattern
3. filter out those with `\` in the string from `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(NF = ifelse(str_detect(NF, '\\d+\\-\\d+'), NF, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(NF, .direction = "down") %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(ID, '\\/'))
```

```
      ID           NF
1   5683 001-00011598
2  10180 001-00011598
3  10208 001-00011598
4  12551 001-00011598
5  13121 001-00011598
6  13306 001-00011598
7  12551 001-00011599
8  12674 001-00011599
9  13306 001-00011599
10 13306 001-00011600
```

data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("27/07/2021", "5683", "10180", "10208", 
"12551", "13121", "13306", "27/07/2021", "12551", "12674", "13306", 
"27/07/2021", "13306"), NF = c("001-00011598", "BASE P/ NOTEBOOK NBC-50BK C3TECH", 
"SUPORTE MONITOR 17 A 32 T1224N ELG", "SUPORTE F160N DUPLO P/ MONITOR 17 A 27 ELG", 
"MINI ADAPTADOR XC-BTT-04 XCELL", "GABINETE PINK TGC-P03P T-DAGGER", 
"CASE HD + SSD CGHD-G34 EXBOM", "001-00011599", "MINI ADAPTADOR XC-BTT-04 XCELL", 
"SUPORTE FIXO GENIUS ELG", "CASE HD + SSD CGHD-G34 EXBOM", "001-00011600", 
"CASE HD + SSD CGHD-G34 EXBOM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```